# AND condition added to Array Formula doesn't work as expected

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, import, vlookup

I have the below array which has been working perfectly. It's comparing values from another sheet and if they match what is on this sheet , then it shows verified, otherwise it shows unverified.

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(if(row(T:T)=1, "Certification Status", 
if(A:A="","",
if(lower(vlookup(T:T,importrange("abc123","Course Completion!E:H"),2,0))
&"-"&lower(vlookup(T:T,importrange("abc123","Course Completion!E:H"),3,0))
&"-"&to_date(int(vlookup(T:T,importrange("abc123","Course Completion!E:H"),4,0)))=
lower(I:I)&"-"&lower(U:U)&"-"&F:F,"Verified","Unverified")))))
```

I needed to add a condition to evaluate if a row value contains "SIM" and the Attendance status equals "No" or Blank then show "Unverified", in addition to the other checks. If the row value does not contain "SIM" then use the original formula shown first. However when V:V= SIM and the attendance status equals no or blank, it still shows verified.

What did I do wrong here?

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(if(row(T:T)=1, "Certification Status", 
if(A:A="","",
if(and((U:U="SIM"),(V:V<>"yes"),"Unverified",
if(lower(vlookup(T:T,importrange("1A7U7OY8q4M5zCI3WLrwESMwV_471D_4kF71v30yA438","Course Completion (THINKIFIC)!E:H"),2,0))
&"-"&lower(vlookup(T:T,importrange("1A7U7OY8q4M5zCI3WLrwESMwV_471D_4kF71v30yA438","Course Completion (THINKIFIC)!E:H"),3,0))
&"-"&to_date(int(vlookup(T:T,importrange("1A7U7OY8q4M5zCI3WLrwESMwV_471D_4kF71v30yA438","Course Completion (THINKIFIC)!E:H"),4,0)))=
lower(I:I)&"-"&lower(U:U)&"-"&F:F,"Verified","Unverified"))))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AND & OR are not supported under ARRAYFORMULA. use `*` & `+`

for OR:

```
if((V:V="SIM")+(lower(V:V)="yes")
```

[image]

if you need AND you cant have the same column in both cases so this is just example if 2nd column is W and not V:

```
if((V:V="SIM")*(lower(W:W)="yes")
```

[image]

Comment: Updating to that still doesn't show unverified. 

    =ArrayFormula(iferror(if(row(T:T)=1, "Certification Status", 
    if(A:A="","",
    if((V:V="SIM")*(lower(V:V)<>"yes"),"Unverified",
    if(lower(vlookup(T:T,importrange("abc123","Course Completion!E:H"),2,0))
    &"-"&lower(vlookup(T:T,importrange("abc123","Course Completion!E:H"),3,0))
    &"-"&to_date(int(vlookup(T:T,importrange("abc123","Course Completion!E:H"),4,0)))=
    lower(I:I)&"-"&lower(U:U)&"-"&F:F,"Verified","Unverified"))))))

Comment: @Mark can you share a copy / sample of your sheet?

Comment: How do I go about doing that? Do you want an actual copy of it or will a screenshot suffice?

Comment: @Mark answer updated

Comment: Thank you. My brain is not working today. The assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: @Mark if `V:V=SIM` its not something else and if `V:V<>yes` then its something else. you cant use AND for `V` to be `SIM` and not to be `yes`. it is not logical.

Comment: Good to go now! My slow brain today didn't update the SIM column properly. Thank you.